# Unable to SSH into AWS Ubuntu 18.04 Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ubuntu-18.04, network-interface

Hi guys I'm new to cloud and networking so please ask more info If you need... I deployed AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu 18.04 Server. I assigned two Network Interfaces eth0(primary network interface) and eth1, without public IP address. So in order to access it I assigned Elastic IP to my eth1 interface because, I want to use my eth1 for SSH and eth0 for external Internet connection. But I can't SSH with the Elastic IP assigned to eth1. When I assign Elastic IP to eth0 which is primary interface it works perfectly. If I use eth0 for my SSH, Can I use eth1 to connect to Internet?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are configuring something wrong here. I can confirm the SSH access even when the elastic IP is attached to the non-primary (eth1) n/w interface.

To elaborate my setup, I have setup following things:

1. An EC2 instance inside the public subnet of a VPC.
2. Two network interfaces without any public IP address auto-assignment.
3. Security group which allows SSH access from my local machine.
4. Elastic IP attached to eth1 (non-primary) interface.

Following command is used to connect to the instance.

```
ssh -i /path/to/identity/file -vvvv ec2-user@<public-dns-of-elastic-ip>
```

Comment: username should be ubuntu as the OS deployed is ubuntu 18.04, ec2-user is for amazon linux AMI.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. The idea was to demonstrate the working setup. But, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you normally launch ec2 with default setup ,then also you can SSH into instance.
Public IP will always attached to it .There is no need for creating elastic IP.
Just check the security group that it allows your local public IP or 0.0.0.0/0 on Port 22.
As port 22 is used for ssh connection.[image]

Comment: This is incorrect. Public IP will be auto-assigned only if you explicitly want it to happen. By default, it is assigned if your subnet is properly configured. Moreover, I saw that if you try to add two network interfaces to the EC2 instance. auto-assign public-IP is disabled.